Type 'Loader' is not assignable to type 'undefined' in Astro Content Config
I am getting the following linter error in my src/content.config.ts file:

Type 'Loader' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

File contents:
import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

import { glob, file } from "astro/loaders";

const content = defineCollection({
  type: "content",
  loader: glob({ pattern: "**/*.md", base: "./src/content" }), // Lint error
  schema: z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
    category: z
      .enum(["default", "auth", "ui", "cloud", "framework"])
      .default("default"),
    order: z.number().optional(),
    tags: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
  }),
});

export const collections = {
  content,
};


I am following the setup instructions here: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/#built-in-loaders

Let's remove type: "content",.

The solution was to remove the type: "content", line:
const content = defineCollection({
  loader: glob({ pattern: "**/*.md", base: "./src/content" }), // Lint error
  schema: z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    description: z.string(),
    category: z
      .enum(["default", "auth", "ui", "cloud", "framework"])
      .default("default"),
    order: z.number().optional(),
    tags: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
  }),
});

export const collections = {
  content,
};

Thanks @hoangdv!
